# How do I get rpmbuild to download all of the sources for a particular .spec?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am adding some sources to an existing rpm `.spec` file by URL and don't have them downloaded yet. Is there a way to get `rpmbuild` to download the sources rather than doing it manually?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The [`spectool`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/spectool/) utility from the [`rpmdevtools`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Rpmdevtools) package can do this. Just install `rpmdevtools` and point `spectools` at the `.spec` like so:

```
spectool -g -R SPECS/nginx.spec
```

It will download any missing sources into rpm's `%{_sourcedir}` (usually `SOURCES`) directory.

Comment: I can't find which rpm contains spectool in SUSE.

Comment: Is it not simply 'spectool' https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/devel:tools/spectool

Comment: As I wanted to know what the flags mean: "-g, --gf, --get-files   gets the sources/patches that are listed with a URL;    -R, --sourcedir   download into rpm's %{_sourcedir}"

Comment: @aleung Try yum whatprovides "*bin/spectool"

Comment: For SUSE: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel%3Atools&package=spectool

Comment: As @Richlv pointed out, `spectool` downloads files into the `%{_sourcedir}` directory. If you want to know where that is on your own system, you can evaluate it using `rpm --eval "%{_sourcedir}"`. I happen to use this for all sorts of things recently and found it pretty useful to share.

Answer (score 49):

For posterity, there is another way to do it, which does not need any additional tools or downloads:

```
rpmbuild --undefine=_disable_source_fetch -ba /path/to/your.spec
```

Downloading sources automatically is forbidden by default because RPM lacks built-in integrity checks for the source archives. The network has to be trusted, and any checksums and signatures checked. This restriction makes sense for package maintainers, as they are responsible for shipping trusted code.

However, when you know what you are doing and understand the risks, you may just forcibly lift the restriction.

Comment: `rpmbuild --undefine=_disable_source_fetch --define '_sourcedir .' -ba *.spec` finally.

Answer (score 19):

In the spec file, you can place `%undefine _disable_source_fetch` anywhere before the source URL.

For security purposes, you should also specify the sha256sum, and check it in the `%prep` section prior to setup.

Here is a working example:

```
Name:       monit
Version:    5.25.1
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    Monitoring utility for unix systems

Group:      Applications/System
License:    GNU AFFERO GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE version 3
URL:        https://mmonit.com/monit/
%undefine _disable_source_fetch
Source0:    https://mmonit.com/monit/dist/%name-%version.tar.gz
%define     SHA256SUM0 4b5c25ceb10825f1e5404f1d8a7b21507716b82bc20c3586f86603691c3b81bc

%define debug_package %nil

BuildRequires:  coreutils

%description
Monit is a small Open Source utility for managing and monitoring Unix systems. Monit conducts automatic maintenance
and repair and can execute meaningful causal actions in error situations.

%prep
echo "%SHA256SUM0  %SOURCE0" | sha256sum -c -
%setup -q

...
```

*Credits*

@YaroslavFedevych for undefine _disable_source_fetch.

Comment: I tried doing all of this, but I am still not getting RPM to download the tarball from the url. Instead, it tries to use the /usr/src/packages/SOURCES/%name-%version.tar.gz file. FYI I am using the 4.4.2.3 rpmbuild version

Comment: I have just tested on another environment that has rpmbuild 4.12.0.1 and everything worked perfectly (even without the %undefine and %define lines). If it can help others, I found out that download of sources from url instead of using SOURCES/ has been introduced since 4.4.6 https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2007-December/msg00003.html

Comment: I found 4.11.3 does not honor the `%undefine _disable_source_fetch` directive. However, you can still use it on the command line as @Yaroslav mentioned. But @Matt kudos for the SHA checksum code... great idea even if the tarball is already in the `SOURCES` directory.

Comment: Note that there's a typo in the validation code: There must be two spaces between `%SHA256SUM0` and `%SOURCE0`, not just one space.

Comment: @vog Works for me, but I'll take your word for it that that's the case for you. Updated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting sources from a (git) hosting service (github, etc..) there is support for automatically checking it out already built-in, when combined with _disable_source_fetch...

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:SourceURL

For example, for a specific githash from github:

```
%global commit 40-CHARACTER-HASH-VALUE
%global shortcommit %(c=%{commit}; echo ${c:0:7})
Source0:  https://github.com/OWNER/PROJECT/archive/%{commit}/%{name}-%{shortcommit}.tar.gz
...
%prep
%autosetup -n PROJECT-%{commit}
```